# powershell directory prefixes

Tags: windows, powershell

What do you call the prefix portion in powershell directory paths?  Like for certificates, you can do:

```
cd cert:/path/to/certificate
```

or for registries, you can do:

```
cd HKCU:/path/to/registry/key
```

What do you call the "cert:" or "HKCU:" part?  And how do you get a list of which ones are available?

Thx

Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell they are referred to as the "Qualifier" for the path.

The best place to find this information seems to be in the [documentation for the `split-path` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx) options.

> *-Qualifier*
>
> Returns only the qualifier of the specified path. For the FileSystem or registry providers, the qualifier is the drive of the provider path, such as C: or HKCU:.

Having said this, in most other places (including the blurb about the Qualifier itself) these Qualifiers are still referred to as the "Drive", even though it goes beyond the usual `c:`, `d:`, etc. drive volume context.

Different Qualifiers/Drives are supplied by various PowerShell [Providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126186(v=vs.85).aspx).

> A Windows PowerShell provider allows any data store to be exposed like a file system as if it were a mounted drive. For example, the built-in Registry provider allows you to navigate the registry like you would navigate the c drive of your computer. A provider can also override the Item cmdlets (for example, Get-Item, Set-Item, etc.) such that the data in your data store can be treated like files and directories are treated when navigating a file system.

You can use `Get-PSProvider` to get a list of the currently loaded Providers, which lists the "Drives" they add:

[image]